# updating Null Values in multiple columns of a table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I have 64 columns and I am trying to automate the loop process. The loop runs but it shows 0 affected rows. If I update the table, column by column, it works. 
Any idea why its showing 0 affected rows and what can be done ?

```
    update temp set col1 = 'C' where col1 IS Null; -- works (276 rows affected)--

    declare @count as int;
    declare @name as varchar(max);
    set @count = 2;
    while @count < (SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'temp')+1

    Begin
    Set @name = (select name from (select colorder, name from (SELECT * 
            FROM syscolumns WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('temp')) colnames) as cl where colorder = @count)
    Print @name
    update temp set @name = 'C' where @name IS Null;
    SET @count = @count + 1;
    END;
```

Comment: You can't use variables in any kind of column substitution. You need to create dynamic SQL.

Comment: _I have 64 columns and I am trying to automate the loop process_ I cried when I read this.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to use dynamic sql to update the different columns** during runtime as below.

**Note: I just added/modified the dynamic sql part.**

```
    declare @count as int;
    declare @name as varchar(max)
    declare @sql nvarchar (1000)
    set @count = 2
    while @count < (SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'temp')+1

    Begin
    Set @name = (select name from (select colorder, name from (SELECT * 
            FROM syscolumns WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('temp')) colnames) as cl where colorder = @count)
    Print @name

    set @sql = N'update temp set ' + @name + '= ''C'' where ' + @name + ' is null ';
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    SET @count = @count + 1
    END;
```